# how to automate two users credential to PUTTY using batch script?

Tags: linux, windows

I have a local windows 7 machine, where I connect to a local Linux box through putty, and I will have to login twice to get to admin rights.

For example:

1st authentication on PUTTY
user: guest, password: password1

once I am authenticated, i need to become a root by typing 
su

### password

@echo
"C:\Program Files\putty.exe" -load "LinuxServer" -l guest -pw "password1" & -l su -pw "password2"

### @echo

this will bring to the guest login but it will not log in as a root user.

Answer (score 0):

PuTTY doesn't support scripting.  (Nor does it support the -pw option, if you're using the official release.)  So you either need to use different software (like a modified version of PuTTY), or approach this a different way.

I suggest trying a different approach.  Instead of modifying PuTTY, modify the computer that you are logging into.  You can have it automatically run a program like "su" (or, more preferable, "sudo $SHELL").

As for logging in, if you want this automated, you're best bet may be to make it so that the "sudo" (or "su") commands simply don't ask for a password.  This can be done by backing up, and then changing, the /etc/sudoers file.  (Add a "NOPASSWD" switch to the right spot.  You can typically see an example in most default /etc/sudoers files, so just copy the example, except remove the comment character that is disabling the example.)  The easy way to do that is to remove the password entry requirement for everybody, all the time.  That is not necessarily the most secure approach, and many people would dislike that approach due to security concerns.  However, if you are willing to spend the time doing so, you can limit just what types of logins are allowed to elevate permissions without requiring a password.  If you are specific in what is allowed, the security concerns may not be significantly/notably worse than any other method of trying to automate this process (which is what you are trying to do).